# React + Three-Fiber Instances Not Being Displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project where there should be a bunch of small spheres around the molecules, but for some reason, the instance feature is not working! I have tried many methods in order to counteract this, but the end result doesn't display ANY instances.

**CODE:**

```
import * as THREE from "three";

import { useEffect, useState, useMemo, useRef } from "react";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { getMoleculeColour, getMoleculeOpacity } from "./Globals";

export function Particles({ particleRadius }) {
  const tempObject = useMemo(() => new THREE.Object3D(), []);
  const tempColor = useMemo(() => new THREE.Color(), []);

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const meshRef = useRef();
  const colorRef = useRef();

  const globalAtomInfo = useSelector((state) => state.atomInfo.globalAtomInfo);

  const globalSelectedElement = useSelector(
    (state) => state.selectedElement.globalSelectedElement
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (meshRef === null) return;
    if (meshRef.current === null) return;

    const mesh = meshRef.current;

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(globalAtomInfo["density_data"])) {
      const coords = key.split(", ");
      const volume = value;

      //position
      tempObject.position.set(
        coords[0] / 5 - 10.7,
        coords[1] / 5 - 10.7,
        coords[2] / 5 - 10.7
      );

      tempObject.updateMatrix();
      mesh.setMatrixAt(counter, tempObject.matrix);

      // color
      mesh.setColorAt(
        counter,
        tempColor.setRGB(
          ...getMoleculeColour(globalSelectedElement["element"], volume)
        )
      );

      setCounter(counter + 1);
      
      console.log(meshRef.current)
    }
  });

  return (
    // Generate particles...
    <instancedMesh
      ref={meshRef}
      args={[null, null, globalAtomInfo["density_data"].length]}
    >
      <sphereBufferGeometry args={[particleRadius, 30, 30]} attach="geometry" />

      <meshBasicMaterial
        transparent={true}
        opacity={1.0}
        //   opacity={getMoleculeOpacity(
        //     globalSelectedElement["element"],
        //     volume
        //   )}
        attach="material"
      />
    </instancedMesh>
  );
}
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**
https://github.com/wonmor/ElectronVisualized
[image: ElectronVisualized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `needsUpdate` function calls as well as adding a separate for loop to store all the coordinates in one array per axis.

***FIXED CODE***:

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import * as THREE from "three";

import { getMoleculeColour, normalizeData } from "./Globals";

/*
▀█▀ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ ▀▀█▀▀ █▀▀█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▀ █▀▀ 
▒█░ █░░█ ▀▀█ ░░█░░ █▄▄█ █░░█ █░░ █▀▀ ▀▀█ 
▄█▄ ▀░░▀ ▀▀▀ ░░▀░░ ▀░░▀ ▀░░▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▀
DEVELOPED AND DESIGNED BY JOHN SEONG.
SERVED UNDER THE MIT LICENSE.
*/

export function Particles({ particleRadius }) {
  /*
  This is a component of React that generates multiple instances of sphere (individual particles)
  depending on the parameters that are recorded on its blueprint, which is defined in this function
  Parameters
  ----------
  particleRadius: Float
    Contains the desired radius of the particles as a group
  Returns
  -------
  DOM File
    A HTML markup that contains graphical elements; in this case,
    containing instanced mesh that can be replicated throughout the canvas
  */
  const meshRef = useRef();

  const globalAtomInfo = useSelector((state) => state.atomInfo.globalAtomInfo);

  const globalSelectedElement = useSelector(
    (state) => state.selectedElement.globalSelectedElement
  );

  // Write the coordinates based upon its parent JSON data stored in the Redux global state...
  const particles = useMemo(() => {
    const temp = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(globalAtomInfo["density_data"])) {
      const coords = key.split(", ");
      // Normalize the density data in range from 0 to 1...
      const volume = normalizeData(
        value,
        globalAtomInfo["vmax"],
        globalAtomInfo["vmin"]
      );

      // Phase shift and scale the coordinates to match the existing molecule shape that is already generated....
      const x = coords[0] / 5 - 10.7;
      const y = coords[1] / 5 - 10.7;
      const z = coords[2] / 5 - 10.7;

      temp.push({ x, y, z, volume });
    }

    return temp;
  }, [globalAtomInfo]);

  // Anonymous states for instances...
  const anonymousObject = useMemo(() => new THREE.Object3D(), []);
  const anonymousColour = useMemo(() => new THREE.Color(), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
      const { x, y, z, volume } = particle;

      const currentColour = getMoleculeColour(
        globalSelectedElement["element"],
        volume
      );

      console.log(globalSelectedElement["element"]);

      anonymousObject.position.set(x, y, z);

      anonymousObject.updateMatrix();

      // Apply the matrix to the instanced item...
      meshRef.current.setMatrixAt(index, anonymousObject.matrix);
      meshRef.current.setColorAt(index, anonymousColour.set(currentColour));
    });
    /*
    The lines below are arguably the most important part in this code.
    Without them, the changes will not be applied
    and the instances will not be updated accordingly.
    */
    meshRef.current.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
    meshRef.current.instanceColor.needsUpdate = true;
    meshRef.current.material.needsUpdate = true;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <instancedMesh
        ref={meshRef}
        args={[null, null, Object.keys(globalAtomInfo["density_data"]).length]}
      >
        <sphereBufferGeometry
          args={[particleRadius, 30, 30]}
          attach="geometry"
        />

        <meshPhongMaterial attach="material" />
      </instancedMesh>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please note that ```setColorAt``` call does not support Mesh Normal Material. The only supported ones are either Mesh Phong Material (shiny) or Mesh Basic Material if you want that matt look.